# Where does the Discussion Board 'Posted By' data come from?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, lookup-column

We have an email that is sent out when there is a new post to the discussion board via SharePoint Designer workflow. In the email, it shows the user who posted the message or reply using 'Current Item: Posted By'

[image]

A user, Alice *Alpha*, recently changed her name to Alice *Beta*. In all user databases (O365, SharePoint, Azure) her name is updated to Beta but on the email, for the posted by, it still shows Alpha.

When I add the 'Posted By' column to the view, it shows her old name '76;#Alice Alpha'. As seen from the image, it is looking this information up from another list, **where is this list and how do I change it?**

I have changed the email to send the 'Created By' instead of 'Posted By' so I've "fixed" the issue but would still like to know how to get to wherever this information is stored so I can update.

Comment: that's the user information list, under each site collection. you need to run the user profile sync in order to update it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you need to run the user profile sync in order to update all the user information lists. Then the profile will update properly with updated info.